# lvcreate mount previously removed Logical Volume, cento 7

Tags: centos7, lvm, mount, mkfs

So this is what i want to achieve,

- Unmount home partition at /home
- Remove home logical volume /dev/cl/home
- create new home logical volume from the same volume
  group cl and name home
- make xfs filesystem
- mount the new logical volume at /home.

for that i wrote this bash script

```
umount -v /home/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Couldn't not unmount /home"
  exit 1
fi

# delete
lvremove /dev/cl/home

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Couldn't delete LVM /dev/cl/home."
  exit 1
fi

# create home
lvcreate -L2G -n home cl

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Couldn't create a new LVM /dev/cl/home."
  exit 1
fi

mkfs.xfs /dev/cl/home

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Couldn't create a file system for /dev/cl/home."
  exit 1
fi

# restore home
mount /dev/cl/home /home/
```

the script fails at the line mkfs.xfs /dev/cl/home with msg `mkfs.xfs: /dev/cl/home contains a mounted filesystem`, it seems `lvcreate -L2G -n home cl` doesn't really create a new logical volume it just retrieves the previously removed logical volume with the same filesystem and mount it at the same mounting point /home, what could possible cause this?

Comment: If you dont want the previous data, you could try the -f option of mkfs.xfs. It will  format the LV anyway. From man mkfs.ext4 "-f     Force  overwrite when an existing filesystem is detected on the device.  By default, mkfs.xfs will not write to the device if it suspects that there is a filesystem or partition table on the device already."

Comment: i don't have this problem anymore and  i did try with the -f option, it never helped though